# aysnctask download all the images to the same item in the listview

Tags: java, android, image, listview, android-listview

I'm using asynctask to download image to listview with custom cursoradapter. The images are downloaded to the first item in the list and when I scroll down to the second and so on. It's not synchronize and it's not the right picture. What am I doing wrong?
I cant upload pictures so here is my code:

class DownloadItemdPoster extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // get the address from the params:
        String address = params[0];

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = null;

        // the bitmap will go here:
        Bitmap b = null;

        try {
            // build the URL:
            URL url = new URL(address);
            // open a connection:
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // check the connection response code:
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                // not good..
                return null;
            }

            // the input stream:
            stream = connection.getInputStream();

            // get the length:
            int length = connection.getContentLength();
            // tell the progress dialog the length:
            // this CAN (!!) be modified outside the UI thread !!!
            // progressDialog.setMax(length);

            // a stream to hold the read bytes.
            // (like the StringBuilder we used before)
            outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // a byte buffer for reading the stream in 1024 bytes chunks:
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            int bytesRead = 0;

            // read the bytes from the stream
            while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                // notify the UI thread on the progress so far:
                // publishProgress(totalBytesRead);
                Log.d("TAG", "progress: " + totalBytesRead + " / " + length);
            }

            // flush the output stream - write all the pending bytes in its
            // internal buffer.
            outputStream.flush();

            // get a byte array out of the outputStream
            // theses are the bitmap bytes
            byte[] imageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

            // use the BitmapFactory to convert it to a bitmap
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, length);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                // close connection:
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    // close output stream:
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        ImageView itemPoster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewItemPoster);

        if (result == null) {
            // no image loaded - display the default image
            itemPoster.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.defaultitembackground);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Loading Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // set the showactivitybackground to the poster:
            itemPoster.setImageBitmap(result);

        }
    };
}
```

public class MovieAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

```
    public MovieAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.movies_item_layout,
                parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {


        String movieName = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DbConstants.MOVIE_NAME));
        String movieGenre = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DbConstants.MOVIE_GENRE));
        String itemPoster = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbConstants.MOVIE_POSTER));
        String movieRuntime = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DbConstants.MOVIE_RUNTIME));
        String movieRating = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DbConstants.MOVIE_RATING));
        String movieReleasedYear = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DbConstants.MOVIE_YEAR_RELEASD));

        TextView name = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieName);
        TextView genre = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieGenre);
        TextView runtime = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieRuntime);
        TextView rating = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieRating);
        TextView year = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieYear);
        ImageView setItemPoster = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewItemPoster);

        setItemPoster.setTag(1);


        name.setText(movieName);
        genre.setText("*" + movieGenre);
        runtime.setText("*" + movieRuntime);
        rating.setText("*" + "R:" + " " + movieRating);
        year.setText("*" + movieReleasedYear);

        if (setItemPoster != null) {
            new DownloadItemdPoster().execute(itemPoster);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Use picasso or UniversalImageLoader. Links are already given in answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)   to load image from server.
Example :
    `Glide.with(mContext).load(url).into(myImageView);`

Answer (score -1):

You must have to use image loader lib(picasso , volley , universal loader lib) rather than make aysntask to load image from server.

[UniversalLoaderLib](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Example:-

Initiate below code in your adapter or activity once.

```
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loading_icon).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_error_transparent).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error_transparent)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)/*.considerExifParams(true)*/.build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity.getBaseContext()));
```

Use below code where you want to load image from server.

```
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(urladdress, imageview, options);
```